# Excel IF/THEN Conditions

Tags: worksheet-function

I have a cell for shipping weights, and a cell for receiving weights. In a 3rd cell, I want to calculate the difference (receiving minus shipping), but only show that difference if it is more than 1,000 lbs (either positive or negative).

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 2):

This will return either the Weight if over 1000lbs or 0:

```
=IF(ABS(A1-B1)>=1000,A1-B1,0)
```

Comment: WHAT?? I've been looking at this thing all day, trying this and that and those... Amazing!

Comment: @CinZin if it worked please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.